# How to use standard library types

Tags: go

How can I use the standard library type Values found here https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values

I try to import net/url and use Values but go fmt automatically deletes it when i save it.

```
func test(url string) (string, Values) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` here is a variable, not a type.

And please modify `Values` to `url.Values`.

Comment: url.Values was what I was after. Thanks